# cvxpy -> OSQP or cvxpy -> CVXOPT how does it work under the hood?

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization, cvxpy, cvxopt

I have the following simple program:

```py
import numpy as np
import cvxpy as cp
np.random.seed(0)
n = 100
i = 20
y = np.random.rand(n)
A = np.random.rand(i, n).T
x = cp.Variable(n)
lmbd = cp.Variable(i)
objective = cp.Minimize(cp.sum_squares(x - y))
constraints = [x == A*lmbd,
               lmbd >= np.zeros(i),
               cp.sum(lmbd) == 1]
prob = cp.Problem(objective, constraints)
result = prob.solve(verbose=True)
```

I would like to know what happens under the hood. I know that for example the solver `OSQP` is being used thanks to the following variable `prob.solver_stats.solver_name`, I might also decide to use another solver (e.g. `result = prob.solve(solver="CVXOPT", verbose=True)`).

**I would like to know how the problem is treated**. I have the idea that it should be pre-treated since it seems like a double problem (the quadratic minimization one - `y` variable, and the `lmbd` variable as a constraint satisfaction). However, in the `CVXOPT` documentation, it seems to me, that the problem should be only treated as a quadratic or linear problem. In the case of CVXOPT, I know how to use it, and I wouldn't know how to translate the problem in this case, however, `CVXPY` does this with no trouble.

Thanks for the insight.

Comment: Whats exactly the question? 1) Minimization vs. "constraint-satisfaction"? Well... drop QPs and look at (the easier) Linear Programming theory. It's defined on a linear objective and linear equality constraints (we use slacks for inequalities). Nothing special. 2) A (convex) QP is a linearily constrained problem with a (convex)  Quadratic form as objective (+ a linear term). Same as LP, only the objective changes. The "constraint-satisfaction" part is still natural.  Even the more complex [QCQP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratically_constrained_quadratic_program) has these lin equalities

Comment: cvxopt's [QP](https://cvxopt.org/userguide/coneprog.html#cvxopt.solvers.qp) also has these linear equalities (`Ax=b`) which are your "constraint satisfaction" parts.

Comment: Ohhhh... that's true, it's the slack variables, I forgot the basics. However, I would like to know how is that transformed. How do I know the call (with input parameters) `CVXPY` does to `CVXOPT`, `OSQP` or some other. That'd be great to understand what happens and debug better.

Comment: Then read the code. Each solver has a wrapper and recognizing the [cvxopt](https://github.com/cvxpy/cvxpy/blob/master/cvxpy/reductions/solvers/conic_solvers/cvxopt_conif.py) or [osqp](https://github.com/cvxpy/cvxpy/blob/master/cvxpy/reductions/solvers/qp_solvers/osqp_qpif.py) matrices there will be easy. The [conic transformations happening before](https://github.com/cvxpy/cvxpy/tree/master/cvxpy/reductions) on the other hand... which are producing these matrices and also depend on the target-solver (e.g. SOCP vs. QP for a norm_2  objective) -> this will be less fun to read probably.

Comment: Before going full in on those reductions, i would recommend reading the academic papers first, especially the first two links in the [docs](https://www.cvxpy.org/citing/index.html).

Comment: thanks for the insight! =)

Answer (score 0):

Since your problem is a least squares, its matrices are probably only [cast  from least squares to quadratic programming](https://scaron.info/robotics/conversion-from-least-squares-to-quadratic-programming.html) then passed to the QP solver as is. (This operation is simpler than the SOCP→QP conversion mentioned in the comments.)